# Who might create the game pieces?

Tags: custom-game-pieces, prototyping

I've designed a game which requires 3D geometric pieces. For a prototype, I'd like to see these make from metal, and to look elegant. Who might craft such items? I'm not even sure which profession I might investigate.

Comment: Can you use components from other games?  If its just a prototype and your just checking mechanics of a game work does the 'look' matter at this stage?

Comment: Alas their shape is important. They should also have the weight of metal (rather than, say plastic.)

Answer (score 2):

A gold smith/jeweler could do your thing from metal and look elegant, but it might be quite expensive.

Answer (score 2):

A 3D printing service would be an ideal solution.

I have no experience with any of the online services available, but as an example Shapeways seems to offer the option to print in a variety of plastic and metal materials, including the most common metals such as Steel, Silver, Aluminum, Gold, Platinum, Brass, Bronze, etc.

[Shapeways 3D Printing](https://www.shapeways.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If the pieces have an axis of rotational symmetry then I would turn them on the lathe, (or you could search for a local machinist). If not then you could cast them. If you make originals out of wax then you can set them in oil-sand and cast them using the lost-wax method.